# Chinese translation resulting is question marks (????...)

Tags: vba

Long story short, as a test, I am reading data from one cell into a routine that sends non-English words/symbols to Microsoft translator. Upon return, it writes the results in a seperate cell. Unfortunately, because I lack experience when dealing with XMLHTTP, I am banging my head on this one.

That's the plain vanilla short of it. Now here is the long version. I hope I make this clear enough. Forgive me, but remember I am new to this side of VBA...

I'm attempting to leverage a routine that developed by Microsoft and edited by a guy named Patrick O'Beirne, because the way that Microsoft handles tokens has changed supposedly.. Patricks code is here: http://www.sysmod.com/MSTranslator.bas.

Long version...
I am looking to load Chinese data into the routine that uses MSXML2.XMLHTTP to perform a GET on it's way to Microsoft for translation.

This routine works fine on Spanish or French words, but spits out question marks for Chinese Symbols. This may have to do with Chinese symbols being double-byte (?)...

Here is the code. I traced it all the way into the MSHttpRequest function. It looks like it loads the data into oH, but when it comes back  to oH.ResponseText, the symbol change. This is purely a guess on my part.

Anyway, my goal is to send Chinese symbols to Microsoft's translation server and return it in English.

```
Function MSHttpRequest(sRequest As String) As String
Dim sURL As String, oH As MSXML2.XMLHTTP, sToken As String

sURL = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/" & sRequest
sToken = GetAccessToken()
Set oH = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

oH.Open "GET", sURL, False
oH.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & sToken
oH.send
MSHttpRequest = oH.responseText
Set oH = Nothing
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: It's a Unicode/ascii thing read [this](http://blog.nkadesign.com/2013/vba-unicode-strings-and-the-windows-api/)

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but I just found this now. I'm that guy ;-)
I've updated the code now to handle UTF-8, see the post at

https://sysmod.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/microsoft-translator-vba-code-sample/

Please link to the post rather than the .bas file because file names can change.

Answer (score 0):

Very late to post answer, but this may be it.

You need to change the Language settings in Windows so that VBA can access the language you are working on.

Follow below (except the Registry part) and you should be ok.

[How To Display Foreign Characters In Excel VBE](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/how-to-display-foreign-characters-in-vbe.html)